# management instruction in linux

Tags: linux, information-management

Is there any program or service on linux which be able to show which processes are running?

I want a remote one, because i didn't have any access to my linux OS.

I need something such as WMI on window for linux but has installed by default, because i didn't have access to my destination machine.

is there any such service on linux?

Comment: Typically this is realized with OpenSSH and the `ps` command. Both come preinstalled with most Linux systems, but you need to do some minimal setup work.

Comment: thank you for comment, is OpenSSH preinstalled on ubuntu too?